# Azure WebJob ServiceBusTrigger for Sessions

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-webjobssdk

I know it's possible to recieve messages from a service bus queue like:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("inputqueue")] string message, TextWriter logger)
```

But is there also a way to to receive a session via a trigger attribute? Something like ServiceBusSessionTrigger?

Normally one would accept a session like this:

```
var session = queueClient.AcceptMessageSession();
```

But I'd prefer the WebJob SDK to handle how multiple sessions at once can be processed.

**Edit:**
Seems that this currently isn't supported: [see github for feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529)

**Edit 2:** Seems they are [working on this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529#issuecomment-469821143)

Comment: Hi @Zenuka, I have this problem too. Can I ask how you resolved it in the end?

Comment: @JasonSteele, I don't know which blog/tutorial/video I used to implement it like 'var session = queueClient.AcceptMessageSession()' but I think you could use this as a guideline: http://www.cloudcasts.net/devguide/Default.aspx?id=13030

Answer (score 2):

this nuget Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus in 3.1.0-beta3 version support session in azure function. when you install this nuget, 
you will be able to use it like the code below
`[ServiceBusTrigger("testsessionqueue", Connection = "serviceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]`

there you can find nuget : [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/3.1.0-beta3)
and it's a github issue: [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529)

Please bear in mind that it's still a beta

Comment: so can we get ALL the messages that are part of the same session? how?

Comment: this is not helpful. can you forward all messages with a specific session to a queue?

Comment: you need to provide sessionId to your message as property and ensure that your queue or topic support a seesion, then Azure service bus will use the session feature. Azure functions which support session is only an endpoint, so it only grabs messages in a FIFO order.

Comment: More details about session you find on msdn [link](https://learn.microsoft.com//en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions)
it's a main sentence about seesion : "On session-aware queues or subscriptions, sessions come into existence when there is at least one message with the session's SessionId. Once a session exists, there is no defined time or API for when the session expires or disappears. Theoretically, a message can be received for a session today, the next message in a year's time, and if the SessionId matches, the session is the same from the Service Bus perspective."

Comment: Just noting for anyone coming looking that this functionality is now released and no longer in beta.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot receive a session via a trigger attribute, but there is a [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529). If this is something that many people would find useful, it would make sense baked into the core ServiceBus assembly.

Comment: how do you iterate through all messages in a session?

Comment: this feature has now been released https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/16#issuecomment-487233051